# Mapserver set no image available

Tags: mapserver, tilecache

I'm composing a map with aerial footage with mapserver and tilecache. I have tiffs with geo information, then I run gdaltindex to create the shapefiles and then I configure the map file with layers like this:

```
LAYER
    NAME "viana"
    STATUS default
    TILEINDEX "viana.shp"
    TILEITEM "location"
    TYPE raster
    OFFSITE 0 0 0
     PROJECTION                               
       "init=epsg:27492"                    
    END
    PROCESSING "RESAMPLE=BILINEAR"
    PROCESSING "DITHER=YES"
    TRANSPARENCY ALPHA
    MAXSCALEDENOM 54000
    MINSCALEDENOM 423
END
```

How do I set a default image in mapserver for when I'm have no data for some specific area, like an "Image not available at this zoom"? Like http://12f.p8.sl.pt

Comment: You should ask questions like this on http://GIS.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are asking could you clarify? Your question appears to be a MapServer behaviour as a server to provide images, but as an example you point to a client.  When I load the client I can see it making multiple WMS requests to different WMS services and pulling lots of separate images to build the scene, so there is no single `default image` being provided.